# Searching by polygon returning incorrect results

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to search within a polygon in AzureSearch.  I'm using the filter below.  My search returns results, but it is missing a point at -2.54321666666667, 60.6914166666667 and finding one at -2.5437833333333333,
 60.691433333333336.  Both are wrong, right???

$filter=(geo.intersects(BeginningPoint, geography'POLYGON((-2.54321 60.6913,-2.54323 60.6913,-2.54323 60.6915,-2.54321 60.6915,-2.54321 60.6913))'))&$count=true

For easier viewing the points are:
-2.54321 60.6913,
-2.54323 60.6913,
-2.54323 60.6915,
-2.54321 60.6915,
-2.54321 60.6913

Answer (score 2):

Your points need to be defined counterclockwise, not clockwise.
These points `-2.54321 60.6913 (bottom right), -2.54323 60.6913 (bottom left), -2.54323 60.6915 (top left), -2.54321 60.6915 (top right), -2.54321 60.6913 (bottom right)` are defined clockwise, thus flipping them helped.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have to define the polygon in a clockwise order to capture the inside of the area.  So when I reversed points 2-4 it started to return the correct subset.

I'm still a little confused about the original search since it returned a few hundred points (far less then the total remainder in my index), but I don't have time to experiment further right now.